# Working with several instances of DbContext concurrently in EF6 and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, concurrency, dbcontext

I have developed a web application with ASP.NET Web Forms and the Entity Framework 6.

I have read that I should instantiate a new instance of DbContext for each request (with the keywork "using") instead of trying to persist it.

Now, everywhere I need to query the database I'm instantiating the DbContext:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(var tmcc = new TMCContext())
    {
        // querying tmcc entities and/or update them
        // ....

        tmcc.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

But what if two people load the page at the same time? It means that there will be two concurrent instances of DbContext. Isn't that a problem?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 5):

In ASP.NET, every request is processed on its own thread of execution. All the objects you create in the scope of processing that request are only in the scope of that request, unless you explicitly store the object in a shared place, like a static property. This means that your contexts will exist side-by-side without any knowledge of the other instance: a scenario entirely supported by Entity Framework.

The issue of concurrent changes to data is somewhat more problematic - you can conceivably have two users make a change to the same row of data at the same time. Entity Framework and SQL Server will both let this happen. By default, SQL Server will accept both changes in the order in which they were received by the server. If you have conflicting changes, that is one set of changes which are not compatible with another set of changes (e.g. both users update the "Name" field to two different values), the change which is processed last "wins"; that is the change you will see applied to the conflicted column.

Unfortunately, how you want to resolve these issues is quite a big topic, far too big to answer here. It will depend on your user requirements more than anything else - it might be okay to let the last commit win and you can take the easy road. Otherwise, you will have to do a bit of reading around the subject.

Comment: Thank you, I will take the easy road. But what if I'm instantiating the DbContext inside a static method of a static class? I have written several static class with only static methods that also instantiate DbContext. Theses methods are called from ASP.NET code-behind.

Comment: @gilgha Provided you don't *store* the context in a shared place, or otherwise share instances between requests, you're ok to instantiate them however you think best. The key thing is not to share state between requests.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure there will not be a problem with DbContext concurrency if multiple users hit your page simultaneously. However you may have logical concurrency problems because one user may unknowingly overwrite the data of another user. What should you do in this case depends solely on the logic of your application.

BTW I would recommend that you instantiate one DataContext per HttpRequest and use it everywhere and dispose it when the request ends. You can hook on the Begin Request event in the Global.asax to do that and stick the request in Request.Items or somewhere (not static field!) or you can do it properly and use IoC container library and have it create a DataContext for you with a per request lifetime.

Answer (score -1):

Use Linq. You need to add models to your context using DbSet

DbSet project {get; set; }

Then you can get the data from the database

tmcc.projects.tolist();

Comment: I know that.I just want to know if my way of doing it is *concurrent safe*